# material-ui v.1 - define component's background with theme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material-ui v.1 library for React, and want to set background of `Paper` components.

I want to do that using themes.

I'm using top level

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        //type: 'light'
    }
});

<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

What should I put in `createMuiTheme` to do that?

I've tried several options (like `palette:{paper: {backgroundColor: 'black'}}`, and `paper: {backgroundColor: 'black'}`, and `backgroundColor: {paper: 'black'}`) but nothing works.

NOTE: `type: 'light'`, `type: 'dark'` works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to https://material-ui-next.com/customization/themes/, the following property should be used :

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        background: {
            paper: 'red'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [themes documentation](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/themes/#the-other-variables) you will see:

```
{
  "palette": {
    "shades": {
      "light": {
        "background": {
          "paper": "#fff",
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: I now tried: createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        shades: {
            light: {
                background: {
                    paper: '#20b2aa'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
});
Does not help. Note: #fff=white